# Android View inflate by using for loop

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater

**I want to delete view when clicking on a delete icon but it only removes last view whenever I click on delete icon.**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getData().getQualifications().size(); i++) {
        View item = qualificationInflater.inflate(R.layout.student_education_view, null);
        qualificationParentPanel.addView(item);
        TextView college = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.college);
        TextView degree = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.degree);
        TextView percentage = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        TextView start_date = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.start_date);
        TextView end_date = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.end_date);
        ImageView educationDeleteIcon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.educationDeleteIcon);
        college.setText(response.body().getData().getQualifications().get(i).getCollege());
        degree.setText(response.body().getData().getQualifications().get(i).getDegree());
        percentage.setText(response.body().getData().getQualifications().get(i).getPercentage());
        start_date.setText(response.body().getData().getQualifications().get(i).getSessionFrom());
        end_date.setText(response.body().getData().getQualifications().get(i).getSessionTo());

        final int finalI = i;
        educationDeleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("deleteIconPos","------>" +response.body().getData().getQualifications().get(finalI).getId());
               qualificationParentPanel.removeViewAt(finalI);
            }
        });
```

Comment: toast the value of `i` and see

Comment: okay, but how to get view position??

Comment: for your `for` loop you are opening bracket `{`. where are you closing it?

Answer (score 1):

Attach `i` with every `ImageView` using [`setTag`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))

```
educationDeleteIcon.setTag(i);
```

then later

```
 qualificationParentPanel.removeViewAt((int)v.getTag());
```

Answer (score 0):

consider finalizing freshly inflated view

```
final View item = ...
```

and then inside `OnClickListener` you may use

```
qualificationParentPanel.removeView(item);
```

also you should use only local declaration for `educationDeleteIcon`

```
ImageView educationDeleteIcon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.educationDeleteIcon);
```

instead of

```
educationDeleteIcon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.educationDeleteIcon);
```